# "Bearer" is missing from JWT token when Swagger is used

Tags: java, swagger

After upgrading my Java API so that it uses Swagger 3, when testing the Bearer token endpoints through the UI, they keep returning 401. But when I test these endpoints through Postman, they return OK.

**SwaggerConfig.java**

```
/**
 * Configuration settings for Swagger
 */
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Autowired
    BuildProperties buildProperties;

    @Value("${swagger-docs.host}")
    String host;

    @Value("${swagger-docs.protocols}")
    String protocols;

    @Bean
    public Docket api(){
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .apiInfo(
                        new ApiInfoBuilder()
                                .title(buildProperties.getName())
                                .version(buildProperties.getVersion())
                                .build())
                .host(host)
                .protocols(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(protocols.split(","))))
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.demo.example"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .tags(new Tag("API", "API Demo Example"));
    }
}
```

**application.yml**

```
swagger-docs:
  host: ${EXPOSED_HOST:localhost:8088} # public hostname
  protocols: https,http
  path: /swagger
```

What do I need to add in the code for the Swagger to return OK?

FYI the response says:

```
Code- 401 (Undocumented)
Details- Error: Response headers
---
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 0
date: Tue23 Nov 2021 14:48:28 GMT
keep-alive: timeout=60
vary: OriginAccess-Control-Request-MethodAccess-Control-Request-Headers
```

**EDIT 24/11/21**

I noticed that the token passed to the endpoints is different depending on whether I use Postman or Swagger:

- Postman : *"[Controller] jwtToken: Bearer xxx..."*
- Swagger : *"[Controller] jwtToken: xxx..."*

The word "Bearer" is not included in the token when the Swagger is used, and as a result, it can't read it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution did not consider situations where "Bearer" was NOT at the beginning of the Token.

It was removing the first segment of the Token (regardless if "Bearer" was there or not) before trying to decrypt it, resulting in the error.